# Archive of Microsoft's Powershell 2.0 Documentation?

Tags: powershell, documentation, msdn, powershell-2.0, microsoft-technet

When looking up information on a specific cmdlet built into Powershell on Microsoft Technet, you can choose between version Powershell versions 3.0, 4.0, and 5.0. See this page for an example - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt156967.aspx

Is there a page or other site where you can find information on version **2.0**?

Answer (score 3):

A guy named Adam Ringenberg provides some kind of reference http://adamringenberg.com/powershell2/

Answer (score 1):

I found a different link, this still works as of 2017 08 17 https://allunifiedcom.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/powershell_v2_owners_manual.pdf

Comment: Great! The PDF is saved on the [Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150105190542/http://allunifiedcom.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/powershell_v2_owners_manual.pdf) too, so ideally it'll be available on the web for a long time.